# Unable to solve this exercise regarding prepositions

Tags: prepositions

I have some questions regarding prepositions which I am unable to solve, any help is appreciated. I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask.

***In the following passage, fill in each numbered blank with correct form of words mentioned in brackets.***

> That's why Pepsi's campaign was such a success. The campaign broke
>   when we (1) ____ (get) used to the idea of (2) ____ (liberty). Consumer
>   culture was beginning (3) _____ (take) off. Pepsi caught the sentiment
>   and the slogan is the biggest success story in the history of (4) ____
>   (advertisement). The second and third factors that (5) ____ (contribute)
>   to effective advertising are the strength of story it (6) ____(tell) and
>   the 'wow' element that will make it memorable. An ad that simply (7)
>   ____ (state) that a certain soft drink is (8) ____ (make) of mango will not work.

The answers according to me -

1. got
2. libety
3. to take *or* take (confused between the two)
4. advertisement
5. contributed
6. tells
7. states
8. made

Comment: 1) 'were getting', 3) 'to take', 4) 'advertising', 5) 'contribute'

Comment: Remember, random exercises from random textbooks are normally full of random mistakes and dysfluencies. If you're having trouble figuring out what the exercise wants, consider the possibility that you speak better English than the author did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pepsi's dozens of advertising slogans date from 1939. Here's a list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepsi#American_slogans

1.) were getting; 2.) having an alternative to Coca-Cola (or having a choice); 3.) to take; 4.) advertising; 5.) contribute; 6.) tells; 7.) states; 8.) made.

In this strange paragraph, "liberty," "mango" and "will not work" make no sense, the former two having no relevance and the latter unsupported by the evidence presented. No wonder you found it difficult to understand!